# Images from online storage into a JavaScript Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have a friend who wants a very basic website designing, one page of which will be a slideshow of some images. Our issue is, everytime he wants to change the photos, hes going to have to get in touch with me to re-program the website to add these new images.

Is it possible to have the slideshow grab the images from another site where he can easily upload them to (be it storage such as GoogleDrive or photo sharing such as flickr)? If so what would be a suggestion for where the photos would be stored and how I would go about getting them in my slideshow? Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: yes, you can embed offsite images. you would feed the urls of the images to your slideshow, however the slideshow code expects them. sometimes its a JSON list, sometimes it finds existing IMG tags. Even fancier ones might obtain a list of images from an API call. It depends on what your using, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: http://wowslider.com/index.html? Also, you can use predefined names for slides (1.jpg, 2.jpg,etc), put them in e.g. 'slideshow' folder, and your friend can easily replace old slides, with new ones (via ftp - using of ftp client is not so hard to learn, i guess). Also, even better - you can create small php script which will dinamically create html for slideshow, by reading content of slideshow folder, etc,etc...

Answer (score 0):

One very low tech quick and dirty solution with no server coding is to load the IMG URLs from a comma separated list in a text file that he can manually edit. Use jquery.load to load the file and split the string.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a PHP server you can get the path to each image dynamically and just upload images into the directory and always recieve a complete list of all of the images available by making a request or include for the page:

```
<?php
$images = glob('./path/to/your/images/*');
shuffle($images); // for a random list
// or sort($images) 
foreach ($images as $source) {
    echo '<img class="an_image" src="' . $source . '" alt="">' . "\n";
}
?>
```

Put this into a php file and make a request for it and you get a list of image tags (in this case)